# Call method in one fragment, from another fragment (or, get next/prev ID)

Tags: android, user-interface, gridview, imageview

I've got an app set up, following the outline of a Udacity course. There's a MainActivity and DetailActivity, both with fragment. The "main" side queries MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails and shows all thumbs in a GridView. When clicked, a URI is constructed with the `IMAGE_ID`, and the DetailActivity is started. This shows the full-size image + some metadata.

I'm now wondering what it'll take to make "prev" and "next" buttons in my detail UI. Clicking these will open the corresponding (prev or next) image in the detail UI. Technically, this means refreshing the ContentLoader with an updated URI. I just need some way to get the previous and next IMAGE_ID.

I guess I could do this all "locally" within the detailfragment, say by doing a query to get the next ID:

```
SELECT MIN(IMAGE_ID) NEXT_ID FROM thumbnails WHERE IMAGE_ID > ? ORDER BY DATE DESC;
```

where I'd plug in the current `IMAGE_ID` as parameter. Then I could just construct the new URI, and restart the loader. Right? I'd have to figure out just how to implement this as a query to the Content Resolver, but I guess something like this *could* be done.

However, the MainActivity handles the onClick, which takes me to the DetailActivity (thumb -> image) in the first place. It knows the `int mPosition`, even, of the GridView. Wouldn't it be a better solution to just ask the MainActivity (or MainFragment) to give me the prev/next IDs? But then the question is, how do I call a method in MainFragment from DetailFragment? Do I go via Fragment Manager, something like this?

```
Fragment mainfrag = getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MainFragment");
```

And is it correct to get the prev/next ID's like this:

```
int prevId = mPosition-1;
int nextId = mPosition+1;
```

> **Update:** I tried adding a tag to each fragment, and use Fragment Manager to get a reference to the PhotoFragment (from the DetailFragment), but I keep getting `null` when I do:
>
> `PhotoFragment pf = (PhotoFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(PHOTOFRAGMENT_TAG);
>   int position = pf.getPosition();  // crash: pf == null`
>
> Is this because, on a phone, the detail activity/fragment *replaces* the main activity, stopping it? As you can see in MainActivity, below, I have a two-pane UI on a larger screen but there (on a tablet) I get a ClassCastException:
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.android.galleri.app.DetailFragment cannot be cast to com.example.android.galleri.app.PhotoFragment

Anyway, here is the outline of my project. How do I do I call from DetailFragment to PhotoFragment...

## MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements PhotoFragment.Callback  {

    private static final String DETAILFRAGMENT_TAG = "DFTAG";
    private boolean mTwoPane;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (findViewById(R.id.photo_detail_container) != null) {
            mTwoPane = true;

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.photo_detail_container, new DetailFragment(), DETAILFRAGMENT_TAG)
                        .commit();
            }
        } else {
            mTwoPane = false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(Uri contentUri) {

        if (mTwoPane) {
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putParcelable(DetailFragment.DETAIL_URI, contentUri);

            DetailFragment fragment = new DetailFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(args);

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.photo_detail_container, fragment, DETAILFRAGMENT_TAG)
                    .commit();
        } else {

            // launch DetailActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class)
                    .setData(contentUri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

## PhotoFragment  ("main fragment)

```
import com.example.android.galleri.app.data.PhotoContract;


public class PhotoFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private final static int LOADER_ID = 87;
    private PhotoAdapter mPhotoAdapter;
    private int mPosition;
    private GridView mGridView;
    private TextView mEmptyView;
    private int count_mem = -1;
    private static final String SELECTED_KEY = "POSITION";

    // these are the data we want from MediaStore
    private final static String[] THUMBNAIL_COLUMNS = {
            PhotoContract.ThumbEntry.COLUMN_THUMB_ID,
            PhotoContract.ThumbEntry.COLUMN_DATA,
            PhotoContract.ThumbEntry.COLUMN_IMAGE_ID
    };

    static final int COL_THUMB_ID = 0;
    static final int COL_THUMB_DATA = 1;
    static final int COL_THUMB_IMAGE_ID = 2;

    // interfaces
    public interface Callback {
        public void onItemSelected(Uri photoUri);
    }


    public PhotoFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        if (mPosition != GridView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            outState.putInt(SELECTED_KEY, mPosition);
        }
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        mPhotoAdapter = new PhotoAdapter(getActivity(), null, 0);
        GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_photo);
        gridView.setAdapter(mPhotoAdapter);

        mEmptyView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_empty);
        mGridView = gridView;

        // handle user clicking on an image
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                if (cursor != null) {
                    Uri baseUri = PhotoContract.PhotoEntry.buildPhotoUriWithId(cursor.getLong(COL_THUMB_IMAGE_ID));

                    ((Callback)getActivity()).onItemSelected(baseUri);
                }
                mPosition = position;
            }
        });

        if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(SELECTED_KEY)) {
            mPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(SELECTED_KEY);
        }

        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {

        Uri thumbs_uri = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), thumbs_uri, THUMBNAIL_COLUMNS,
                null,null,  // read everything (all thumbnails)
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID + " DESC");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        int antall = 0;
        if (cursor != null) {
            antall = cursor.getCount();

            // register observer onto cursor
            cursor.setNotificationUri(getActivity().getContentResolver(), MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            mPhotoAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
            if (mPosition != GridView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                mGridView.setSelection(mPosition);  // scroll into view
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {
        mPhotoAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

}
```

## DetailActivity

```
public class DetailActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putParcelable(DetailFragment.DETAIL_URI, getIntent().getData());

            DetailFragment fragment = new DetailFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(arguments);

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.photo_detail_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

}
```

## DetailFragment

```
import com.example.android.galleri.app.data.PhotoContract;

public class DetailFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    static final String DETAIL_URI = "URI";
    private static final int DETAIL_LOADER = 0;
    private ImageView mPhotoView;
    private Long mImageID;

    private static final String[] DETAIL_COLUMNS = {
            PhotoContract.PhotoEntry.COLUMN_IMAGE_ID,
            PhotoContract.PhotoEntry.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME,
            PhotoContract.PhotoEntry.COLUMN_DATA,
            PhotoContract.PhotoEntry.COLUMN_DESC,
            PhotoContract.PhotoEntry.COLUMN_DATE_TAKEN,
            PhotoContract.PhotoEntry.COLUMN_DATE_ADDED,
            PhotoContract.PhotoEntry.COLUMN_TITLE,
            PhotoContract.PhotoEntry.COLUMN_SIZE,
            PhotoContract.PhotoEntry.COLUMN_ORIENTATION,
            PhotoContract.PhotoEntry.COLUMN_HEIGHT,
            PhotoContract.PhotoEntry.COLUMN_WIDTH
    };

    static final int COL_IMAGE_ID = 0;
    static final int COL_DISPLAY_NAME = 1;
    static final int COL_DATA = 2;
    static final int COL_DESC = 3;
    static final int COL_DATE_TAKEN = 4;
    static final int COL_DATE_ADDED = 5;
    static final int COL_TITLE = 6;
    static final int COL_SIZE = 7;
    static final int COL_ORIENTATION = 8;
    static final int COL_HEIGHT = 9;
    static final int COL_WIDTH = 10;

    private Uri mUri;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle arguments = getArguments();
        if (arguments != null) {
            mUri = arguments.getParcelable(DetailFragment.DETAIL_URI);
        }
        // get ID from URI
        if (mUri != null) {
            mImageID = PhotoContract.PhotoEntry.getImageIdFromUri(mUri);
        }

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);

        mPhotoView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pic_frame);
        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        if (mUri != null) {
            return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                    mUri, // URI passed in
                    DETAIL_COLUMNS, null, null, null);
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor data) {

        if (!data.moveToFirst()) {
            return;
        }

        String thumbData = data.getString(COL_DATA);
        Bitmap thumbBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(thumbData);
        mPhotoView.setImageBitmap(thumbBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(DETAIL_LOADER, null, this);
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On a phone, this wouldn't work. When the user starts the `DetailActivity`, the `MainActivity` does not keep running "in the background". So, to persist the data, I created a new class, `Utility`, which holds the cursor and the position of the last click -- both set from `PhotoFragment` (i.e. from `MainActivity`). Then, `DetailFragment` can get the cursor and position from `Utility`. Seems to work :)

```
import android.database.Cursor;

public class Utility {

    private static Cursor mCursor;
    private static int mPosition;

    public static void setCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        mCursor = cursor;
    }

    public static Cursor getCursor() {
        return mCursor;
    }

    public static void setPosition(int position) {
        mPosition = position;
    }

    public static int getPosition() {
        return mPosition;
    }
}
```